# How to show advanced search form on the site dashboard?

Tags: search, alfresco

Is it  possible to implement advanced search form in a dashlet which takes place on the site dashboard - landing page? What would be the best way to do that?

Answer (score 1):

There is share side service available for retrieving the form in alfresco.

http://host:port/share/service/components/form?itemKind=type&itemId=[type of document]&formId=[form_id]&mode=edit&showSubmitButton=true&showCancelButton=true&htmlid=args1

Using this service you can get the content and and display it inside any html element.

You may need to add other things like , setting the submition URL etc..

**Other option** is to design everything by your self.Meaning you need to define all fields in dashlet and use javascript to submit that value of element.Search form is ultimately submitting values on below URL.

http://host:port/share/page/dp/ws/faceted-search#searchTerm=&query={"prop_cm_name":"asd","datatype":"cm:content"}&scope=all_sites

So you can take values from fields and than create above url using values and hit that URL pragmatically.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I will try both ways.